# What is the probability of all three companies going bankrupt?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

So I had a question on a test which I can't stop thinking about.

The question is: say that there are three companies $(A,B,C)$ that are independent of each other. The probability of company $B$ going bankrupt is $0.20$. The probability of both $A$ and $C$ going bankrupt is $0.07$, and the probability of $B$ and $C$ going bankrupt is $0.08$. If we know that at least two of the companies have gone bankrupt, what is the probability of all three of them having gone bankrupt?

$$P(B) = 0.2$$
$$P(A\cap C) = 0.07$$
$$P(B\cap C) = 0.08$$

Isn't this just $P(\textrm{all three bankrupt}\; |\; \textrm{at least two of the companies having gone bankrupt})$?

And if we use the rule $P(A\;|\;B) = P(A)$ for independent events (if we can?), shouldn't the answer to this question just be $P(\textrm{All three bankrupt})$ Which would just be $P(A) \cdot P(B) \cdot P(C)$?

Is there something I've done wrong? This was a question on an exam for a statistics basic course at UNI.

Just confused if this is really the correct answer or if its supposed to be way harder?

Comment: You know $P(B),$ Find $P(A), P(B)$ Then use independence to find numerator and denom of conditional probability. Divide.

Comment: Im with you all the way until your last comment (divide).
() = 0.175
() = 0.40.
(∩B∩) = 0.014.
What would be your next step?

Comment: Once you have the numerator and the denominator, divide to get the conditional probability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $P(\textrm{all three bankrupt}\; |\; \textrm{at least two bankrupt})$.......if we use the rule $P(A\;|\;B)= P(A)$ for independent events (if we can?), shouldn't the answer to this question just be $P(\textrm{all three bankrupt})?$

But the event that all three have gone bankrupt is *not* independent of the event that at least two have gone bankrupt.

[image]

$$P(\text{all three bankrupt}|\text{at least two bankrupt})\\=
\frac{P(\text{all three bankrupt})}{P(\text{at least two bankrupt})}\\=
\frac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(A\cap B)+P(B\cap C)+P(C\cap A)-2P(A\cap B\cap C)}\\=
\frac{0.014}{0.035+0.08+0.07-2(0.014)}\\=8.92\%$$

Comment: Thanks for clearing that part up. What I still fail to grasp is why (all three bankrupt | at least two bankrupt) does not become (all three bankrupt ∩ at least two bankrupt) / (at least two bankrupt). Basically: why aren't we using the conditional probability formula? Sorry if I'm being slow, this really messes with my brain.

Comment: @Think_I_Cant No worries. [all three bankrupt ∩ at least two bankrupt]= [all three bankrupt], no? After all, region A∩B∩C in the Venn diagram is fully contained within the union of the regions A∩B and B∩C and C∩A.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh yeah now I get it! Thanks a lot, it finally "clicked".

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ denote the number of companies that go bankrupt.

Then to be found is:$$P(X=3|X\geq2)=\frac{P(X=3,X\geq2)}{P(X\geq2)}=\frac{P(X=3)}{P(X\geq 2)}$$
Here: $$P(X=3)=P(A\cap B\cap C)$$ and:$$P(X\geq2)=P(X=3)+P(X=2)=$$$$P(A\cap B\cap C)+P(A\cap B\cap C^c)+P(A\cap B^c\cap C)+P(A^c\cap B\cap C$$I leave the rest to you.